# Making HTML variable available to JavaScript in Rails render

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0,3

In my form, I have this render:

```
<%= render partial: "makes", locals: {form: 'new_admin_car', car_id: car_id} %>
```

I need to access the car_id variable as in:

```
var car_id  = $('select#car_ymm_year_id').attr("car_id");
```

The trigger fires but car_id is undefined.  Obviously, it is not available as a local variable.  What changes do I need to make to access it?

Thanks...

Comment: In short, there are a few ways but the easiest is to define a new JS variable from an ERB template using a Ruby variable. Also see http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

Comment: Have a look at the "gon" gem, which does exactly what you want...

Comment: I appreciate both comments.  The railscast and the gon gem will be helpful.  However, they both are directed toward passing variables from the controller to JS, which was not my objective.  Even so, great and useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you have to ask someone else the question so that you can figure out the answer.  That was certainly the case here.

As I asked the question and thought about it later, I realized the basics of what was happening.  Render is passed to build the HTML being referenced.  So, that HTML partial is where I needed to set the variable.

The technique will differ depending upon the specific implementation in use.  In my case, I am using simple_form.  So, I added the following to the input statement that is within the partial.

```
{input_html: {form: form, car: car, car_id: car.id}, ... }
```

This made car_id available to JS when the event was triggered.